# Edit a remote file using SSH in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, ssh

Below is the code snippet I have written.

1. This tries to fetch the server name and file name through the arguments
2. I am stuck at editing the remote file after the server name and corresponding file name are fetched.

Command run: `server.pl sox3d1 TEST50`

File `server.pl`:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use XML::Simple;
    
    my $host=$ARGV[0];
    my $db_host=$ARGV[1];
    
    my %servers;
    $servers{"ser14316.local.net"}=["sox3d1","sox3d2"] ;
    $servers{"ser143hn.local.net"}=["sox4d1","sox4d2"] ;
    $servers{"ser14441.local.net"}=["sox6d1","sox6d2"] ;
    $servers{"ser18163.local.net"}=["soxuat61","soxuat62","soxuat63"] ;
    $servers{"ser1444r.local.net"}=["soxuat51","soxuat52","soxuat53"] ;
    
    
    my $files=
    {
      db=>"/appl/$host/db_info.ref",
    };
    
    my %groups_by_host;
    for my $group (keys(%servers)) {
       for my $host (@{ $servers{$group} }) {
          push @{ $groups_by_host{$host} }, $group;
       }
    }
    
    
    my $server = $groups_by_host{$host};  # we get the server name via variable $host
    my ( $ssh_to_server )=@$server; # This is the server to ssh
    
    my $dest_file=$files->{"db"} ; #This will fetch the file from the remote server
    
    print "$ssh_to_server","->","$dest_file \n";
```

The file in this server has to be edited and below are the steps to do that via ssh.

1. Search for the string `$host` (i.e `sox3d3`) in the remote file `$dest_file` by doing ssh to server `$ssh_to_server`
2. Replace the string `TEST30` with `TEST50`

The file is a semicolon-separated file

File content in remote server (`db_info.ref`):

```
sox3d3   ;/appl/sox3d3/current   ;TEST30     ;TEST30      ;USER_10   ;USER_30
sox4d4   ;/appl/sox4d4/current   ;TEST40     ;TEST40      ;USER_20   ;USER_40
```

So, the 3rd and 4th columns (`TEST30;TEST30`) should be replaced with `TEST50` as per input.

Have tried the below code to get it working

as i said i was trying for a one line and had many variables  in the command , the below worked actually

Update 1:

This basically ssh's the server and changes the file accordingly

```
  system(
     'ssh' => ('-q',$ser),
     'sed' => ('-i -E', qq('/$host/s#([^;]+;[^;]+;)[^;]+;[^;]+#\\1$db_host 
     ;$db_host #') , $dest_file),
```

Comment: Maybe look at https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Remote

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do that, is to retrieve the remote file, edit it locally and then copy it back to the remote server. You could use any of [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH), [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) or [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) for doing the file transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this?

```
my $destination = sprintf( '%s@%s', $user, $host );
my $file        = '/path/to/some/file.txt';
system(
  'ssh' => $destination,
  'sed' => ( '-i', 's/TEST30/TEST50/g', $file ),
);
```

The `ssh` documentation shows you can pass a command after the ssh destination. When you do this, ssh will log into the server, run that command, then log out again, instead of dropping you into the shell on the server.

So you can use that to run `sed` to edit the file.

Comment: This will replace TEST30 everywhere, not just on lines which contain the server name, and not just when separated by semicolons on both sides. This is not hard to fix per se (`sed -i '/sox3d3/s/\bTEST30\b/TEST50/'`, still making some simplifying assumptions about the input and the available `sed` dialect) but I guess the OP would want to see this done actually in Perl.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to say that we are not allowed to install libraries ☹️

Comment: @tobyink , no I haven’t tried like this but how do I execute the system command here , never tried this , can u please elaborate on how to run this . I ll try

Comment: also sed command doesnt work with variables , have to hardcode the values
ex : 
system(
  'ssh' => ('-q',$ser),
  'sed' => ( '-i', 's/iam/$db_host/', $file ),
);

Comment: This Worked  :   'sed' => ( '-i', "s/iam/$db_host/", $file ),

Comment: @tripleee ; The command sed -i '/sox3d3/s/\bTEST30\b/TEST50/ is just replacing the first entry in the line and i have TEST30 twice , is there any other flag to achieve this ?
Though this works from command line , from script it is failimng 
system(
  'ssh' => ('-q',$ser),
   sed => ( '-i', "/sox3d3/s/\bTES30\b/TEST50/",$dest_file),
) ; , Am i doing anything wrong

Comment: Like any basic `sed` tutorial will tell you, add the `g` flag to replace all occurrences on a line.

Comment: Updated to add `/g`. @LearningCpp

Comment: i have already tried it ,and  i have updated the post too, dont know why it is not updated :(  , i have updated the latest sed command used just to edit 4th and 5th columns rather than seraching for them  .

Comment: @tobyink : can i copy a file through  the same system command , actaully i have to make chnages in an xml file too, but its easir to copy it from server to local and then make chnages and copy it back

Comment: Use `scp` to copy files between servers, not `ssh`.